# Basic string array manipulation in C

Tags: c

I have this:

```
int main()
{
    char m[] = "12aa34"; 
    for (int i = 0; m[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        //printf("%c\n", m[i]);
        m[i] = m[i] + (isdigit(m[i]) ? -2 : 1);
        puts(m);
        printf("\n");
    }
    //printf("\n");
    //puts(m);
    return 0;
}

puts(m) output: /2aa34
                /0aa34 
                /0ba34 
                /0bb34 
                /0bb14
                /0bb12
```

First question regarding puts(m) output:
I thought after some digging that it has something to do with ASCII. Are the operations done at the representation level so to speak? I checked it and relates somehow with the result of `/` (i.e decimal value of `1` is `49 => 49 - 2 = 47` which is `/`), then for `2` is `50 => 50 - 2 = 48` which is `0`, then for `a` is `97 => 97 + 1 = 98` which is `b` and so on.

Second question regarding first commented `printf`:

`m[]` is a char of pointers right? Now isn't supposed to be changed as the string gets modified by the `m[i] = m[i] + (isdigit(m[i]) ? -2 : 1);` to give me the new values instead of old ones?

Comment: What is "a char of pointers" supposed to be? `m[]` is an array of chars. And chars are literally integers, so there is no difference between `49` and `'1'` (mind the quotes). And `47` is the same as `'/'`. So `'1' - 2 == '/'`. What exactly did you expect?

Comment: So in ASCII, two characters to the left of `1` is `/`.

Comment: @Siguza array of chars i wanted to write and thus a pointer.

Comment: Array and pointers in  C are intimately linked, but not identical. The name of the array is to all intents and purposes a pointer to the first element, and you can get the second element using the [] operator, which works on both arrays and pointers. When you pass the array to a subroutine, it "decays" to a pointer. the practical effect of which is that you need to pass the length as well.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean "The name of the array is to all intents and purposes a pointer to the first element" - except in the case of `sizeof`. ;)

Comment: ... and the address-of operator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct the representation of a char in C is a number.

Ie in C,  a 'char' is usually a 'signed char' or a one byte number, in the range -128 .. 127.  You can assign characters to it  for example m[1] = 'a',  but this is still an integer assignment. The only difference is that it has only a range of -128 .. 127

The ASCII character set is 0 .. 127, but char can also represent the negative numbers.

If you used unsigned chars instead then the range is considered to represent 0..255 instead, and the characters above 127 are called control characters.

This statement

```
char m[] = "12aa34";
```

means create a 7 byte array on the stack and initialise it with the byte values corresponding to the ascii characters for '1','2','a','a','3','4','\0' (nul)

The only thing that could be considered a pointer is the variable m itself, when you use it. However here the m storage would be allocated on the stack, not the heap.
What happens is that when you compile your program, the compiler stores the string "12aa34\0" in the compiled code. When your function is called, the compiled code will allocate at least 7 bytes on the stack by incrementing the Stack Pointer and will then initialise those 7 bytes by copying over it from the "12aa34" string that was stored in the code. So, then your code is perfectly allowed to change the values in the m variable on the stack.

If you did this:

```
char *m = "12aa34";
```

Then instead of m having 7 bytes of storage on the stack, which are the byte values '1' (49), '2' (50), etc.   Instead m would refer to the location of 8 bytes allocated on the stack which are a pointer (64 bit memory address)   pointing *directly* to the "12aa34" string in memory which was stored in the executable by the compiler and was loaded into memory when you executed your program.  In this situation, you should not be allowed to modify m[i] because the part in memory where the executable code was loaded, is usually read-only.
This is made clearer in C++ where the 'type' of a string literal "example" is not just "char *", but " char const *", which represents that you cannot modify the char values.

In your example code, your commented printf should indeed print each unmodified character before you change it.

To help understsnd what is happening, try something like this:

```
char *orig = ”12aa34";
char *another = "12aa34";
char m[] = "12aa34";

printf(" %p  %s\n",  orig,orig);
printf("%p %s\n", another, another);

printf("%p %s\n", m, m);

m[0] = 'x';
printf("%p %s\n", m, m);
```

What you will find is that the pointer and string values of 'orig' and 'another' will be identical.

Whereas the pointer value printed for 'm' will be different, though the string value will be the same at first, and then different after you modify it.

Comment: a `char` **is** a byte (but a byte in C might have more than 8 bits too), but the value can be signed or unsigned; it is not certain that a `char` can be negative - this is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Characters are integral values, and adding/subtracting `1` from them affects the integral value.   If that's what you mean by operations at the "representational level", then - yes - that is what happens.

For the ASCII character set, `'0' - 1` (i.e. subtracting the numeric value `1` from the character `'0'`) is the character `'/'`.   Note that, although ASCII is supported by quite a few implementations (compilers, libraries), it is not actually required by the C standard.   However, there is not yet any standardised character set for which the character `'0'` has a numeric value of zero.

As to your second question ....  Firstly, your statement that "`m[]` is a char of pointers" is incorrect (in fact, it is meaningless).  `m` is an array of `char`.   Second, the commented out `printf` prints out `m[i]` (the `i`th character in the array `m`) in every iteration of the loop BEFORE that character is actually modified.    With the statements (for every iteration of the loop)

```
    printf("%c\n", m[i]);
    m[i] = m[i] + (isdigit(m[i]) ? -2 : 1);
    puts(m);
    printf("\n");
```

there is a fixed sequence of events.  The first `printf()` statement outputs the value of `m[i]`, THEN `m[i]` (i.e. exactly one character in `m`) is modified, then `puts(m)` outputs the whole array `m`, then a newline is output.   If you somehow expect `m[i]` to be modified before the first `printf()`, then you need to think again.    The order of statements in a source file matters.

Comment: Well, and the execution char set of C simply cannot have '0' to have value 0.

Comment: True, but I doubt there is much value in explaining the execution character set in an answer to this question, since the OP has demonstrated (both in original question and in edits) lack of understanding of the difference between a `char` and a pointer.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really underdtand your question, but I'm trying to help.

In your loop, you first modify one character of the string, and then print the whole string stdout. And that seams to work, because, as you said, those output characters are due to ASCII charset.

```
char m [] = "foo";
```

Is the same as writing

```
char * m = "foo";
```

The only difference is, that you can initialise an empty string with the first method when writing

```
char m [20];  
m [19] = '\0';
```

You would create an empty string with lenght 20 chars. You have to set the last char to \0, so that the string is terminated

When using the char * way, you have to create slightly different loops, like:

```
char * ptr;
for (ptr = m; * ptr != '\0'; ptr++){
    //Do something, * ptr is used to get and modify the current value
}
```

Accessing an char [] without an index, like (only the name) that refers to the pointer of the first element in the array or string.

I hope this was want you wanted, if not, let me know.

Comment: `char m[]` is nowhere near the same as `char *m`; also you still can access the `char *ptr` with indexing - one doesn't *have to* create slightly different loops with pointers; they're just a *possibility*.

Comment: In that application it does not make a differnce since he is assigning a string literal to it, so it doesnt make a difference  if he uses an array, which you would use if you had to create the object in memory, or just store the pointer to the string directly

Comment: the statement "char[] m = ...    is the same as writing char * m = ..." is not correct at all, they are completely different as described above. One allocates a 8 bytes on the stack and then initialises those 7 bytes to the string value. The second allocates an 8 byte pointer and initialises it to the memory location (pointer value) of the existing "12aa34" string in memory, which is a pointer to memory where the  .data segment of the executable was allocated when the updating system loaded the code into memory

Comment: It's not the same and it does make a difference and it is clearly that exact difference that the asker is trying to understand. So it's really misleading and unhelpful to state something which is completely false in this situation where it's the crucial difference.